# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: App ID length must be 32 characters

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

Facing issue when i try to run the JUnit test class

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: App ID length must be 32 characters.
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:244)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: App ID length must be 32 characters.

```
at net.hockeyapp.android.utils.Util.sanitizeAppIdentifier(Util.java:127)
at net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager.initialize(CrashManager.java:490)
at net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager.register(CrashManager.java:124)
at net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager.register(CrashManager.java:97)
at net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager.register(CrashManager.java:85)
at app.fabhotels.FabHotelApp.checkForCrashes(FabHotelApp.java:64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are installing `CrashManager` inside the `onCreate()` of your `Application`.

If you have a complex `Application` class it is probably unsuitable to use it in your Robolectric tests.

One solution is to create an empty `Application` class:

```
public void EmptyApp extends Application { 
}
```

Then your test setup can look like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(application = EmptyApplication.class, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", sdk = 23)
```

Comment: @Thanks David I resolved my issue by supplying hockyapp id in my Application class

Comment: @VivekSingh that's great. You can post an answer if you want